# Block access to web site during certain times, at the computer level, no access to router

Tags: website, blocking

I need to block access to certain websites during certain time. For example I want to block www.example.com from 0600 - 2000. The settings should be password protected. If I could redirect them to [here](http://www.merlinmann.com/rightnow/) during the block hours it would be a bonus.

I do not have access to the router and the OS is Vista.

There are several related [questions](https://superuser.com/search?q=block%20website%20certain%20times) but I couldn't find a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

[K9 web protection](http://www.k9webprotection.com/) can block certain sites, and it can shut off internet access during specified periods of time, but I don't think it can just shut off certain websites at certain times of day. It does however let you enter a password to temporarily bypass the security blocks. It is also local to the computer it is installed on.